# Finding formulas for sums

Tags: number-theory, summation, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

I know that $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) = 0$ whenever $n >1$, and I know that $\sum_{d \mid n} \phi(d) = n$. How can I use this in order to give a formula for $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d)\phi(d)$?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\phi(n/d)$ in that last sum?

Comment: Both $\mu$ and $\phi$ are multiplicative, so is $\mu \phi$; a sum over the divisors of $n$ is also multiplicative, meaning the values are completely defined once you know the value at primes and prime powers.

Comment: @mixedmath I don't think so, let $n=p$ for a prime, $p$, then the sum he has written is $2-p$ and the other sum is $p-2$.

Comment: @AdamHughes yes I am sure, however I think mixedmath´s point was that $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d)\phi(d) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(n/d)\phi(n/d)$.

Comment: Can you prove that, whenever $g(n)$ is multiplicative (meaning $\gcd(a,b)=1$ implies $g(ab) = g(a) g(b)$) the same applies to $h(n) = \sum_{d|n} g(d)?$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function

Comment: @AdamHughes: Ah, I was actually thinking you were referring to the $\phi(d)$ sum, for whatever reason. Sorry about that

Comment: No problem I can totally see that happening to me too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't immediately know a solid convolution for the thing you have written, we'll do this the old-fasioned way:

By multiplicativity we write:

$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)=\prod_{p|n}\left(\sum_{\alpha}\mu(p^\alpha)\phi(p^\alpha)\right) = \prod_{p|n}\left(1-(p-1)\right)=\prod_{p|n}(2-p)$$

so your answer is just

$$\prod_{p|n}(2-p).$$

Comment: Crap, wrong convolution. One second to edit. X_X

Comment: in longer cases you can delete, edit while deleted, then undelete.

Comment: @WillJagy thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note that the guy asking replied to your first query with "yes I am sure" meaning it is not your convolution, it is exactly what he typed in originally. Which can also be answered, it is just not as pretty.

Comment: Eww. Well, time to overhaul this excellent thing into something TERRIBLE. T_T

Comment: @AdamHughes Did you miss the product sign in the last equality? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sodan oops, yep. I'll fix that right up.

Comment: Just looked into it again, dont know why but I forgot how the first equality follows, may you enlighten me.

Comment: It's by multiplicativity of the function we're summing.

Comment: This is not how I first thought about it. I am not familiar with multiplicativity properties (Just started the course), can you explain this further?

Comment: Adam  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/etiquette-how-to-deal-with-spoon-feeding-requests